# RegEx - Filtering out empty strings between delimiters

Tags: c#, regex

So i've been googling for a while, but maybe I can't find the right keywords for my search...

Anyway, I'm trying to find myself a Regular Expression that can filter out empty spaces between my delimiters.

Let's suppose I have a string like `Hey;Hi;Hello;` I'm getting just `Hey`, `Hi`, and `Hello`. And thats exactly what I want.

Now the problem arises when there's an input like `Hey;&nbsp&nbsp;Hi;;` (I'm just using the `&nbsp` to represent input spaces).

If this happens I need to get only `Hey`and `Hi`, any ideas how it can be achieved through a Regular Expression ? I'm using C# objs, in case that helps in any way.

Thanks.

Comment: In this case I just would use split() and trim() and no regular expressions.

Comment: If your problem is with `&nbsp;` only, just `string.Replace` it before splitting the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use regex:

```
var input = "Hey; &nbsp &nbsp; Hi; ;;";
var result = input.Split(';')
                  .Select(c => c.Replace("&nbsp", " ").Trim())
                  .Where(c => c.Length != 0);
foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```